# Shadow DOM and custom styling

Tags: html, css, dom, shadow-dom

So I've read this [article](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/) and from what I understand, each native browser widget is actually a combination of basic elements, styling and scripts. This begs the question - if they are consisted of basic building blocks, does that mean that there is a way of customizing them through JavaScript? And I don't mean in the replacement sort of way, as some JavaScript libraries/plugins do - simply by accessing their "Shadow DOM" properties and adding some CSS styles to them, for example. Also, [this page](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/Component_Model_Use_Cases) has some use cases, but nothing practical.

Anyone ever tried anything like this? Is it possible at all? Downsides?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My main concern would be that the implementations of the shadow DOM would be different between browsers and then you are basically back to needing some sort of library to deal with it. I'm not sure if that is the case, but its worth considering. Also, given that there are so many widget libraries available and that is the standard way of handling most of these issues, is it worth taking on a whole new set of unknown issues instead of just working with known elements?

Comment: True, there are many options already. However, all of them (I think) use replacements and are based on hacky approaches. I'm only considering this because of performance improvements (however insignificant), and more as an experiment than anything to be put to practical use. Of course, if there is a way to achieve it, it wouldn't hurt to have native styling to every browser component.

Comment: I don't have too much academic insight into it, my advice is more from a practical perspective. Also, I wouldn't call the other ones "hacky" as I think you mean it in a negative way just because they are not native controls. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Didn't mean it in a negative context, I apologize if it sounded so. No, I simply meant that as the best available and tested solution (it is hacky however, since it uses replacements, overlays etc.), which certainly doesn't mean it's the only possible. Will research into this further, and update if I find anything of significance. Thanks again.